# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The transaction count is not 0

Tags: sql-server, powershell, transactions, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am trying to run an Azure Runbook that executes a database maintenance stored procedure. However, `$command.ExecuteNonQuery()` gives me the error Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The transaction count is not 0 in the following PowerShell script:

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'Credential'

$userName = $credential.UserName

$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$connectionString = "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=False;User ID=$userName;Password=$password"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$connection.Open()

$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()

try {
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    $command.Connection = $connection

    $command.Transaction = $transaction
    
    $command.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    
    $command.CommandText = "dbo.IndexOptimize"
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Databases", "USER_DATABASES")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinNumberOfPages", "500")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FragmentationMedium", "INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FragmentationHigh", "INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FragmentationLevel1", "5")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FragmentationLevel2", "30")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateStatistics", "COLUMNS")
    
    $command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogToTable", "Y")
    
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    
    $transaction.Commit()
}
catch {
    try {       
        $transaction.Rollback()
    }       
    catch {
        # Microsoft recommends to catch and log and/or ignore rollback exceptions
    }
    throw
}
finally {
    $command.Dispose()
    
    $transaction.Dispose()
    
    $connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: Not all versions of Ola's dbo.IndexOptimize stored procedure have the @MinNumberOfPages parameter. What happens if you connect to the target server with SSMS and use the same command (inside a transaction)?

Comment: Why use a transaction if the maintenance script has its own way of handling transactions? Also no need to catch and rollback, if you use a `finally` with a `$transaction.Dispose`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for this. I was migrating this functionality from an on-site SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database. The on-site job has `IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0)` => `IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Running the following produces the same error: `BEGIN TRANSACTION` `EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize...` `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. Per @Charlieface comment, I am removing the transaction from my PowerShell script, since the maintenance script handles transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola's maintenance scripts do their own transaction handling. So you don't need your own transaction.

Remove the following lines as well as the `catch`:

```
$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()
...
$command.Transaction = $transaction
...
$transaction.Dispose()
```

Also the whole `catch... $transaction.Rollback` was not necessary anyway even if you wanted a transaction. Since you have a `finally` with `$transaction.Dispose` this will get handled for you anyway.